# How to hiding UITabbarController tabBar without removing safearea

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller, safearealayoutguide

I'm hiding the tabBar of a `UITabBarController` for a certain screen with a `UIScrollView`. However, that causes the scrollView to cover the entire iPhoneX screen. How can I hide the tabBar without having the scrollView cover the safe area?

I've attempted using `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` like so:

```
scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How do you set constraints for UIScrollView in the first place? There might be a workaround to disable constraint for scrollview's bottom == tabbar's top and activate the new one.

Comment: Are you using interface builder?

Comment: I have the same issue, do you fix it?